# Sitecore 9.1 + PHP 7.2 = all form fields being removed by Sitecore on POST events

Tags: configuration

Mixing Sitecore and PHP has worked for all versions up till 9.1. Now PHP pages render fine, but when you post to a page, the `$_POST` collection is empty now.

I took a vanilla Sitecore 9.1 instance and ripped it apart until it was basically an MVC site again. Once I got it that far, it worked again. I have disabled all the modules and handlers in the `web.config` working my way through configs now. I have to imagine it is a `httpRequestBegin` or a pipeline.

Just looking for any thoughts on diagnosing this. I have disabled my test page with the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes`, but Sitecore is still clearing the post variables.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes">
        <patch:attribute name="value">/cauer.php</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### Update:

I added a debugging processor at the beginning and end of `httpRequestBegin` and `httpRequestEnd`. In 8.2 U7 when my php file is in the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` I get a hit at the beginning of the `httpRequestBegin`. But in 9.1 I do not get the hit. It is skipped. They seem to be handling the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` urls differently in 9.1.

### Update 2

This is reported as a bug. Being worked on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this as an issue when I created this question. Support worked through it and created a patch for it. It was a complete replace of the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.dll

Reference support ID 305761 for the fix.